# Chrome Driver crashes on send_keys

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, exception

I am a Windows 10 Python user.
I use the most recent Python version from JetBrain (PyCharm)
Until recently my code had no problem with the `webdriver.send_keys` command.

I have recently tried to use the latest version of both, the Chrome browser and chromedriver (2.39)
With those "improvements" the driver's `send_keys` function suddenly started failing (regardless of the browser i was using - EDGE, Firefox, Chrome...)

I am getting the following error:

```
unknown error: call function result missing 'value' (Session info:
chrome=67.0.3396.62) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700
0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT
10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest chrome you have to use latest selenium driver which is something around 3.12.XX.
Try to setup the chrome driver and chrome on the list.

[Compatibility between Selenium WebDriver and the major web browsers](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/compatibility-between-selenium-webdriver-and-the-major-web-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your chrome version, to check out the chromedriver compatibility with your chrome version check this [LINK](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)